Why is returning 404 (should be 401) when unauthorized with cookie auth in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API?
When the user is not authorized and he tries to make a request, the status code should be 401, but it's 404.
Here is my how I added cookie auth. In controllers I basically use attribute [Authorize] and authentication works, everything is fine, but when unauthorized user tries to make a request status code returned is 404, not 401.
program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostContext, services, configuration) =>
{
    configuration.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.File("Logs/log-.txt",
        rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day);
});

builder.Services.AddMapper();

builder.Services.AddApplication();
builder.Services.AddPersistence(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySql"));
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddConfiguredCors();
builder.Services.AddConfiguredIdentityCore();
builder.Services.AddConfiguredSwagger();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var app = builder.Build();

#endregion

#region Configure

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();

    using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
    var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PfsDbContext>();
    DbInitializer.Initialize(db);
}

app.UseCustomExceptionHandler();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("AllowAll");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

#endregion

I was just googling and didn't find the answer

The reason why you faced the 404 error is you are using the cookie auth, the cookie auth will redirect the un-login user to the login page, but your cookie authencication setting doesn't contain this part and there is no login page to let the user login in, so it return the 404 error.
You could test it by directly use the API method url inside the browser, you will find it redirect to other page, like below:

To avoid this, you could set the CookieAuthenticationEvents OnRedirectToLogin method to directly return the 401 error.
More details, you could refer to below coeds:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });


Thank you for your answer, but I still have the problem, I addedf this event, and still got 404.
I made request to the method:
'''
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable>> GetAll()
{
var query = new GetBlockListQuery
{
};
var vm = await Mediator.Send(query);
return Ok(vm);
}
'''
The controller than includes the method has attribute [Authorize]

Please share your current program.cs, controller codes to let me see why it happened. I also need check the url for your route you have used is right. Besides, as I said inside the answer, you could test it directly inside the browser to see which url you have used show the 404 error.

when I'm trying to check it directly with url I type this "https://localhost:5001/api/block" and get this "No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:5000/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2Fblock"

Here's my controller, I shared program.cs when I asked the question above.
'''
public sealed class BlockController : BaseController
{
private readonly IMapper _mapper;
public BlockController(IMapper mapper) =>
_mapper = mapper;
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable>> GetAll()
{
var query = new GetBlockListQuery
{
};
var vm = await Mediator.Send(query);
return Ok(vm);
}
'''

I don't think this is related with your controller, the redirect url is the right for the cookie authentication, could you please share your current program.cs?  Have you replaced my codes with your cookie settings?
